# Pass all bash function's arguments to docker exec command?

Tags: bash, docker, quoting

I am trying to make an alias outside my container that will call a command inside the container:

```sh
CONTAINER="my-container-name"
container_echo() {
    docker exec "$CONTAINER" bash -c "echo $@"
}
```

I see this output:

```
$ container_echo "this is a test" second third
this is a test
```

So this doesn't quote my arguments correctly, it only passes the first argument. I've also tried `docker exec "$CONTAINER" sh -c "cp \"$@\""` but I get a `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this would be simply:

```
docker exec "$CONTAINER" echo "$@"
```

If you really wanted to do it via `bash -c`, you should shell escape each word and concatenate them into one string:

```
docker exec "$CONTAINER" bash -c "echo ${*@Q}"
```